# Installing Windows 7 Home Premium or Professional RC

Tags: windows-7

I downloaded the Windows 7 RC from the Microsoft site. I have it running under VM Ware workstation. I would like to have Windows 7 Home Premium or Professional instead of the Ultimate edition. Is there a way to downgrade my existing installation to Home Premium or Professional? Is there a separate download for these editions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not yet.  For the betas and RC's, the only product key available to the public is Ultimate.  When the production version comes out there will be separate product keys for each.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open image in "UltraISO"
2. Open folder "sources"
3. Delete file "ei.cfg"
4. Save image.

Comment: What would this do?

Answer (score 0):

deleting ei.cfg works to allow install of any version ( don't enter key when asked, will install anyway) BUT the ultimate keys don't work, so it's only good for 30 days without alternate hacking.